# Looking at entering new data in a regression model

Tags: regression, residuals

Been puzzling this for a while so hopefully can help.

Have a dataset 1 of which I have a regression equation. I want to see how well this model can predict my new data set - let's call data set 2.

Can I calculate the ESS and RSS by doing

ESS = sum(predicted y from dataset2 - average response of real y from dataset2)^2
&
RSS=sum(real y from dataset2 -predicted y from dataset2)^2

and then use these to calculate the Rsq value and compare the difference between r sq of original eq and rsq of this new dataset.

Or does the average y used in ESS calculation need to be from the original dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your output? What type of regression are you doing? How do you want to evaluate your model, precision, recall, accuracy?

Comment: Hi, doing linear regression, the output is continuous variable not sure on the rest I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you looking for some accuracy metric like MSE?

Comment: Yeah essentially.